# how to set up reference crystal for free energy calculation using Thermodynamic Integration(TI)

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, entropy, crystals, molecular-dynamics

I'm a graduate student in chemical engineering. I'm calculating free energy of disordered solid crystal in confinement(especially about a spherical confinement) using the method in the following paper.

> Schilling, Tanja, and Friederike Schmid. "Computing absolute free energies of disordered structures by molecular simulation." (2009): 231102.

I cannot figure out how to make reference crystal for a crystal which is non-cubic geometry when they are formed in a sphere cavity like following work.

> De Nijs, Bart, et al. "Entropy-driven formation of large icosahedral colloidal clusters by spherical confinement." Nature materials 14.1 (2015): 56-60.

How can I make reference crystal? In the paper above, it simply mentioned that

> The lattice sites are taken from representative conﬁgurations of the system featuring the desired cluster symmetry.

When I am given a cluster made up of arbitrary N particles. For TI method, I should calculate N lattice site in a spherical cavity. Is there any procedure to make the reference crystal lattice site? I cannot figure it out what it means to make the configuration of the system featuring desired cluster symmetry.

I also wonder if this technique reflects interaction between confinement and particle to calculate free energy. In the above paper, they give a potential function between the particle and the spherical confinement. I wonder it is well reflected to the free energy calculation.